# What's the zero vector in a subspace of the space of all functions $F(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm having trouble visualizing the zero vector in $W\subset F(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$, given $W = \{ f \in F(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}) : f(3) = 0\}$.

Wouldn't this simply be $f(x)=0$ so that when you add it (coordinate-wise) to any $g \in W$, you would get the very same $g$?

If so, how can I prove it's in $W$? It can't even be in $W$, can it? A function in $W$ maps $3$ to $0$, so something that maps everything to $0$ fails the condition to be in $W$.

Comment: ? If a function maps everything to zero, then it certainly maps $3$ to zero.

Comment: ... I made myself look really dumb, didn't I. I even put everything in English sentences and somehow didn't catch that. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function mapping everything to zero, also maps $3$ to $0$. Therefore, it trivially belongs to the set of all functions vanishing at $3$.

Remember that a subspace of a vector space shares the same zero as the original vector space itself. Therefore, if $F(\mathbb R,\mathbb R)$ has as the "zero vector" the function that takes everything to zero, then the zero vector of every subspace is also this function which takes everything to zero. If you are trying to show something is a subspace, then the zero vector of the space itself must be part of this subspace.